# Invoking Powershell commands in a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Can anybody help me please in writing the below Powershell commands as a batch file? I will execute the file by command prompt. I don't have the option of creating a ps1 file and executing it through the command prompt.

Thank you.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-4)   
$path = "T:\FolderName"   

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -include *.txt | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

Get-ChildItem \\123.456.78.910\Y$\Z\*.txt | Where { $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) } | % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination T:\FolderName }
```

Comment: check this : http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5526

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke powershell.exe with the -command parameter to do this. You can also have more than one powershell command by separating them with semicolon. You should double-double-quote any double-quotes.

Here's an example:

```
powershell -command "$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-4); $path = 'T:\Folder Name';Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -include *.txt | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force"

powershell -command "$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-4); $path = 'T:\Folder Name';Get-ChildItem \\123.456.78.910\Y$\Z\*.txt | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) } | % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination 'T:\DestinationFolderName' }"
```

EDIT:
Here is a one-line version of it with only a single set of ""; all quotes inside are single '

```
powershell -command "$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2); $path = 'D:\Folder\Folder Name'; Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -include *.txt | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force;Get-ChildItem \\123.456.25.123\D$\folder*.txt | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) } | % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination 'D:\Folder\Folder' }";
```

Comment: Thank you but it gives the following error:
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:175
+ Get-ChildItem \\123.456.78.910\H$\Y\*.txt | Where { $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) } | \Folder\AnotherFolder\AnotherFolder } <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (}:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken    

I'm on Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP2 and the version of the Powershell should be 1.0, if that would help. Thanks.

Comment: I have to admit I can't try this in PowerShell 1.0, but let's try it with single quotes instead of doubledoublequotes. I'll edit the code in place

Comment: powershell -command '$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2);$path = "D:\Folder\Folder";Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -include *.txt | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force';                
powershell -command 'Get-ChildItem \\123.456.25.123\D$\folder\*.txt | Where { $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) } | % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination D:\Folder\Folder }';

Comment: You have single quotes and double quotes in the opposite places. Also it looks like you're trying to put both powershell commands on one line. This can work if you like, but you shouldn't specify "powershell.exe -command" twice; only at the beginning. Also you have a Where where you should have a Where-Object I believe

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate your help. After dealing with this old version of Powershell, achieved what I needed by creating a separate .ps1 file and executing it by a batch file (not the ideal solution but it works :)).